# tr: convert apostrophe to ASCII

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a [Right Single Quotation Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) to an [Apostrophe](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm) using `tr`.

```
tr "`echo -e '\xE2\x80\x99'`" "`echo -e '\x27'`" < a > b
```

given a UTF-8 encoded file called `a` which contains this example:

```
We’re not a different species
“All alone?” Jeth mentioned.
```

OS X uses the BSD `tr` and produces a nice result:

```
We're not a different species
“All alone?” Jeth mentioned.
```

Ubuntu uses the GNU `tr` and produces this nasty result:

```
We'''re not a different species
''<9C>All alone?''<9D> Jeth mentioned.
```

How can I accomplish this conversion in Ubuntu?

Comment: Also tried: tr $'\xE2\x80\x99' $'\x27' < a > b
with same results.

Comment: This is good to know [ASCII and Unicode quotation marks](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html)

Comment: `echo It’s easy | perl -CS -Mutf8 -pe "tr/’/'/"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try some other tool, like `sed`:

```
$ sed "s/’/'/g" <a
We're not a different species
“All alone?” Jeth mentioned.
```

Or, since we are doing simple translation, use the `y` command for `sed`:

```
$ sed "y/’/'/" <a
We're not a different species
“All alone?” Jeth mentioned.
```

[GNU `tr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html) doesn't work presumably because:

> Currently `tr` fully supports only single-byte characters.
>   Eventually it will support multibyte characters; when it does, the `-C`
>   option will cause it to complement the set of characters, whereas `-c`
>   will cause it to complement the set of values.  This distinction will
>   matter only when some values are not characters, and this is possible
>   only in locales using multibyte encodings when the input contains
>   encoding errors.

And `’` is a multibyte character:

```
$ echo -n \' | wc -c
1
$ echo -n ’ | wc -c  
3
```

Comment: `sed` is much nicer for this kind of work.

Comment: To explain the last part further: `tr` is replacing each of the three bytes separately with `'`, hence `'''` as well as the broken sequences where it has replaced two of the three bytes in the similar characters `“` and `”`. It should instead understand the three bytes as together meaning one character, and replace that instead.

Answer (score 9):

If you also want to convert the double quotes, and perhaps other characters, you could use [GNU `iconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/iconv.1.html):

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit < a
We're not a different species
"All alone?" Jeth mentioned.
```

The `//TRANSLIT` suffix tells `iconv` that for characters outside the repertoire of the target encoding (here ASCII), it can substitute similar-looking characters or sequences automatically. Without the suffix, `iconv` will give up as soon as it finds an untranslatable character.

Note that `//TRANSLIT` seems to be a GNU extension: [POSIX `iconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/iconv.1posix.html) doesn't support it.

Comment: +1. If you are converting a text from one character set (or encoding) to another, it can be sensible to use a tool designed for that purpose.

Comment: @deltab your solution also replaces double quotation marks which OP don't want to replace them.

Comment: @KasiyA Maybe they should.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of these `awk` solutions:

```
awk '{gsub(/\xE2\x80\x99/, "\x27");print}' file # with Hex ASCII code

awk '{gsub(/’/, "\x27");print}' file

awk '{gsub(/\342\200\231/, "\47");print}'  file # with Octal ASCII code

awk '{gsub(/’/, "\47");print}' file
```

Or

```
awk '{gsub(/’/, "'"'"'");print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-s` option of `tr` :

```
$ echo "We’re not a different species"|tr -s "’" "'"
We're not a different species
```

From `man tr` :

```
--truncate-set1
          first truncate SET1 to length of SET2
```

Comment: your solution also replaces double quotation marks which OP don't want to replace them

Comment: Ah, indeed, thanks for pointing this out.  I'll leave this answer for reference.